# highcharts-ng - adding popover to legend items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm trying to add a popover to the legend items for one of my charts. I'm using twitter bootstrap and have tried the javascript method as well as the template method with no luck. When I try to use the javascript method on the chart's load event the chart.legend.allItems array is always empty, which is odd, because if I print the chart.legend property to the console I see the allItems property with a length of 4. If I print the chart.legend.allItems property to the console it shows the length as 0. In any case, the allItems array is not loaded when the chart's load event fires. The javascript method for the popover results in a $(...).popover is not a function error because the ".highcharts-legend-item" is undefined when load fires. It seems like all the chart properties and elements aren not, in fact, loaded when this event fires.

***load event***

```
  events: {
      load: function(e) {
         $(".highcharts-legend").popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'}).hover(function() {
         $('.popover').appendTo($(document.body));
      });

      }
```

***template***

```
legend: {
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    layout: 'vertical',
    x: 0,
    y: 2,
    labelFormatter: function () {
      return '<span>' + this.name + '</span><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>';
    },
    useHTML:true
```

***Edit***
I forgot to load popover.js from bootstrap but that didn't completely fix the issue. The only time I'm able to get the popover to display is passing the ".highcharts-legend" selector to jquery. Trying to use ".highcharts-legend-item" or any child element of ".highcharts-legend" doesn't display the popover. Any ideas?

Comment: If that items are not rendered yet, then how about using `setTimeout( function () { .. popover code here .. }, 0)` ? I guess you can't delegate events like `$('.highcharts-legend').on('mouseover', '.highcharts-legend-item', callback)` ?

Comment: Fixed with setTimeout! Thanks, man!!